# Laravel static call of Overrided Eloquent's first() method

Tags: laravel, methods, eloquent, overriding

if I override eloquent's first() method I can not call the method statically (Through facade) as I would expect. I would expect that implemented __callStatic() method will be used (implemented in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`), but that's not the case.

So I tried to implement the magic method myself. I still cannot access overrided first() method statically.

> ErrorException: Non-static method Entity::first() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context.

```
class Entity extends Eloquent
{
    public function first($columns = ['*'])
    {
        if (Cache::tags(static::getTags())->has('first')) :

            return Cache::tags(static::getTags())->get('first');
        endif;

        $result = parent::first($columns);

        if ($result) :

            Cache::tags(static::getTags())->put('first', $result, with(new static)->ttl);
        endif;

        return $result;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {
        $instance = new static;

        return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $parameters);
    }

}
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: The goal is to add extra "Caching" functionality between application and database request. That means that I check if model is already cached before I make database call. If it's the case I'll return cached model....
The goal is to be possible to call the overrided eloquent's first() method statically as well as by instance.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Laravels built in caching](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/cache)?

Comment: But that's not my problem. The problem is as I described above in the post.

Comment: I understand that but I suspect a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I don't think you should have to override `first()` to implement some caching of your own...

Comment: :) I think that's not my case. I already use implemented laravel's Caching system. I think the best layer to implement checking for cached models is in the place where I try it now.

Comment: Okay that's your choice. See my answer on how you can do it :)

Answer (score 3):

I've expressed my doubts about the necessity to override `first()` for caching purposes, but of course it is technically possible to do it.

You have to create your own `Builder` class for that:

```
class MyBuilder extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {

    /**
     * Execute the query and get the first result.
     *
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static|null
     */
    public function first($columns = array('*'))
    {
        if ($someCondition) :
            return 1;
        endif;

        return parent::first($columns);
    }
}
```

And then make your model use this builder by implementing the `newEloquentBuilder` method:

```
public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
{
    return new MyBuilder($query);
}
```